# How to prevent REPL from truncating output?

Tags: julia

The Julia REPL truncates output based on the window size of my terminal. For example, in a 10 line tall window, I get the following output:

```
julia> collect(1:50)
50-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
  ⋮
 49
 50

julia>
```

How can I prevent the REPL from truncating output like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, is with the command `repr` (it shows the result as a string):

```
julia> repr(collect(1:50))
"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,
30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]"
```

Another way, is with the command `show`:

```
julia> show(collect(1:50))
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,3
0,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]
```

<sub>tested with Julia Version 0.4.3</sub>

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, using Julia Version 1.4.1, the correct way would be to use @show. The semicolon suppresses the printing of the truncated version:

```
julia> @show collect(1:50);
collect(1:50) = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,3
0,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]
```